# Operator's norm

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $T$ be a linear densely defined operator on a Hilbert space $H$ and $L$ be a selfadjoint operator with discrete spectrum and $T^{-1}$ is bounded
such that $$\|Tf\| \leq M \|Lf\|^{a}\|f\|^{1-a}, \quad\forall~f \in \mathcal{D}(L),$$ where $0< a<1$ and $M$ is positive constant. In this case, this implication is it always true?
$$\|L^{-1}Tf\|\leq M \|f\|^{a}\|L^{-1}f\|^{1-a}$$

and $L^{-1}T$ is it bounded?

Comment: please the tite of this question must be changed "norm operators"

Comment: By the way, $\alpha<1$ or $\alpha\in(0,1)$? Also, does the first inequality hold for a given $\alpha$ or for all $\alpha<1$?

Comment: I have changed $T^-1$ to $T^{-1}$. I suppose that's what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the implication: *If
$$
\|Tf\|\le M \|L^\alpha f\|, \quad \text{for all}\,\, f\in {\mathcal D}(L^\alpha), 
$$ 
then*
$$
\|L^{-\alpha}T\| \le M,
$$
to hold, you need that $L^{-\alpha}$ is bounded, or ${\mathcal D}(L^\alpha)\cap {\mathcal D}(L^{-\alpha})$ dense in $H$.

In the second question the correspond inequality would be
$$
\|L^{-\alpha}T\| \le M_1+M_2\|L^{-\alpha}\|.
$$

Comment: With the above hypotheses, can I say that $L$ is invertible and have bounded inverse?

Comment: No you can't. Take $L$ defined on an orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$ of $H$ as follows $L^{a}e_n=n^{a}e_n$, if $n$ odd and $L^{a}e_n=n^{-a}e_n$, if $n$ even, and $Te_n=n^{-a}e_n$, if $n$ even and $Te_n=e_n$ if $n$ odd. Then the original assumption holds for $M=1$, and $\|L^{-a}T\|=\infty$.

Comment: http://www.google.tn/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeepblue.lib.umich.edu%2Fbitstream%2Fhandle%2F2027.42%2F24433%2F0000706.pdf%3Fsequence%3D1&ei=IHK4UpqMG4us7Qaf_oD4Dg&usg=AFQjCNFi7DB30styr9Ro9jDKShN58esb3w&bvm=bv.58187178,d.d2k&cad=rja

Comment: See inequalities 2 and 12

Comment: @salma I think it is better to provide direct link in the form http://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/24433/0000706.pdf?sequence=1 than a link encoded as a part of Google link. (If DOI is available, it would be even better.) If your question comes from reading that paper, it should be mentioned in the original post.